# UK Secondary School - how advanced (or not) is level 5-8?

Tags: secondary-education

My son has just finished his first half-term at secondary school (year 7). I have just received an email saying that the school has set him in a maths class based on current and previous results, and that he will be covering level 5-8 topics.

It does not mention whether he's in a top, middle or bottom set and I have no frame of reference for the levels he is studying. Where does level 5-8 stand in the grand scheme of things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the numbers don't correspond exactly to lettered grades, a 5 is an old C (or C+), an 8 is an A or A+.  There's no way to tell if he's in a top set, as there might be a set doing level 7 to 9, or there might not be.

Comment: Thanks. So that’s C’s and A’s at GCSE? Bearing in mind he’s only year 7.

Comment: That's projected for year 11.  So they expect people in that class to get C-A in year 11.